# How can I use a variable in React's state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to use a variable set in a method in my state so I can get dynamic css styles in return.

When I use the code below, I have an 'alpha is not defined' error

I removed as much as I could from the code :

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);
this.state = {
  current: 1,
  animCardActive: {static object of css properties, works as intended},

  // This is where I'd like to use a variable to get dynamic css, only left zIndex for the exemple
  animCardInactive: {zIndex: 1000 - (alpha * 100)}
 };

_handleStyle(id) {

  // The variable I'd like to use in state
  let alpha = Math.abs(this.state.current - id);

  if(id === this.state.current) {
    this.isActive = true;
    return this.state.animCardActive;
    } else {
      this.isActive = false;
      return this.state.animCardInactive;
    }
}
render() {
  return (
    <div className='main'>
      {cards.map((project, i) => (
        <Card
            key={i}
            style={this._handleStyle(i + 1)}
            />))}
    </div>
);
```

What I also tried but get a zIndex: NaN :

- Using this syntax in my state :

`animCardInative: zIndex: 1000 - (Math.abs(this.current - (this.props.key + 1)) * 100)`

- Defining Alpha in my state (although it doesn't look look good practice) as Alpha: Math.abs(this.current - this.props.id)

Is there a valid solution to this or am I approaching this the wrong way ?

Comment: So move the variable above the state declaration?

Comment: Doesn't work, 'this.current' is not defined, I guess because state hasn't been defined yet. FWIW I tried below too and get the NaN error described in my post.

Answer (score 0):

Your context is not defined when you call your `_handleStyle` method. For `this` to be defined, you need to invoke `_handleStyle` differently. Right now it loses the context. You have two options:

#### Option 1: Bind `this` in constructor to `_handleStyle`

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    current: 1,
    animCardActive: { ... },
    canimCardInactive: {zIndex: 1000 - (alpha * 100)}
  };

  this._handleStyle = this._handleStyle.bind(this); <--- do this
}
```

#### Option 2: Bind `this` during invocation

```
render() {
  return (
    <div className='main'>
      {cards.map((project, i) => (
        <Card
          key={i}
          style={() => this._handleStyle(i + 1)} <--- or do that
        />))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: I know abut binding this for methods, I just don't need it here. To be thourough I tried binding it and it still won't change the fact that alpha is not defined when called in state.